# What is the difference between the various HTTP methods?

Tags: http

I'm reading about RESTful Web Services and I know there are GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, and POST methods, I'm just wondering how you know when and where to use them.

Answer (score 2):

```
PUT = object creation
POST = object update / taking some action with side effects
DELETE = object deletion
GET = Normal page, no side effects
```